# how to get header controls in data bound TreeView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have TreeView with hierarchical data binding. I want to get TreeViewItem.Header controls not my MVVM. I can get TreeViewItem using TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex() method... but how to get TreeViewItem.Header ?

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
var item = TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(...);
var header = ((TreeViewItem)item).Header;
```

However it may not be a good idea:  Generally any code that requires access to the header control itself (as opposed to the model) is poorly written and should be rewritten to use data binding instead.

Comment: Thanks. But header contains my model not controls. I need controls, because I must change one value of control. Why I don't want to change model? Because I need functionality that is control wide, not model wide. This functionality is in place editing of TreeViewItem.Header text, I must swap TextBlock to TextBox control.

Comment: You can swap a TextBlock with a TextBox using data binding in many ways.  Generally I just have a flag such as "InPlaceEditing" in my view model, and use a data trigger in your template to swap the TextBlock for the TextBox.  A couple of other solutions I've used are: 1. Use an attached property to automatically swap the template, which was good for changing a whole UI at once, and 2. Use a binding with a converter to set the control's Template.  WPF has so many powerful mechanisms for controlling this via data binding it would almost be a crime to not to use them.